# XSLT: Normalize space after filtering some tags

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Here is a source XML:

```
<desc> first
  <useless>  second</useless>third
  <useful>word</useful>
</desc>
```

...which I am trying to "clean", like:

```
   <desc>first second third
      <useful>word</useful>
   </desc>
```

My attempts in writing templates start with this...

```
<xsl:template match="desc">
    <xsl:variable name="txt" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="txt1" select="normalize-space($txt)"/>
    <desc>
        <xsl:value-of select="$txt1"/>
    </desc>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="useless">
    <xsl:variable name="txt" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="txt1" select="normalize-space($txt)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$txt1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

...but obviously it's not enough!

Here is the result...

```
   <desc>first secondthird word</desc>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see how that single sample explains the rules you want to apply to "normalize" white-space. To "get rid" of an element node and only process its content it suffice to use e.g. `<xsl:template match="useless"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` and process the rest with the identity template. But I haven't understood which white-space needs to be preserved and which has to be stripped or normalized.

Comment: You even seem to want to insert blanks or where does the space between `second third` in the wanted result come from?

Comment: The pure title "normalize after filtering" could obviously achieved by running the input first through a mode that removes the elements you want to remove, store that result in a variable and run it through a second mode where text nodes are normalized. Only I don't see which text you want to normalize and when/where you even want to insert spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know the 'mode' option. I am not sure how to use it... may be:
<xsl:apply-templates mode="normalize" select="$txt1"/>
in the "useless" template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A result very similar to the one you show could be produced by:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="desc">
    <desc>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string-join(text() | useless/text(), ' '))"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="useful"/>
    </desc>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whether that fits your purpose is not clear. As mentioned in the comments, an example is no substitute for stating the rules.

Comment: Thanks, this fits exactly my purpose:
(1) normalizing space under <desc>
(2) getting rid of a tag below while keeping the text
(3) adding a space after the removed tag